# Oracle 10g on VM

Tags: oracle10g, virtual-machine

Good day! Does anyone know if Oracle 10g forms and reports work on a Vitual machine with Windows XP OS? Can anybody suggest links for configuration if ever? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/as-certification-r2-101202-095871.html, looks like it might. Did you try?